# Elastica add documents overrides existing ones

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

When i try to add new documents to an index type , i loose existing documents which are overwritten by the new added ones . The problem can be related to the id of each added document ??

Here is the code :

```
     $elasticaClient = new \Elastica\Client(array(
                'host' => $this->container->getParameter('elastic_host'),
                'port' => $this->container->getParameter('elastic_port')
            ));
     $elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('app');
           $elasticaIndex->create(
            array(
                'number_of_shards' => 4,
                'number_of_replicas' => 1,
                'analysis' => array(
                    'analyzer' => array(
                        'indexAnalyzer' => array(
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => array('lowercase', 'mySnowball')
                        ),
                        'searchAnalyzer' => array(
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                            'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase',    'mySnowball')
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter' => array(
                        'mySnowball' => array(
                            'type' => 'snowball',
                            'language' => 'German'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            true
        );
     $elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType('type');
      $mapping = new \Elastica\Type\Mapping();
      $mapping->setType($elasticaType);
      $mapping->setParam('index_analyzer', 'indexAnalyzer');
      $mapping->setParam('search_analyzer', 'searchAnalyzer');
      $mapping->setProperties(array(
            'id'      => array('type' => 'string'),
            'title'     => array('type' => 'string'),
            'duration'     => array('type' => 'string'),
            'start'     => array('type' => 'string'),
            'end'     => array('type' => 'string'),
        ));

        // Send mapping to type
        $mapping->send();

    $documents = array(); 
            foreach($medias as $media) { 
                $id = uniqid() ;
                $documents[] = new \Elastica\Document(
                    $id,
                    array(
                    'id'       => $id,
                    'title'    => $media['title'],
                    'duration' => $media['duration'],
                    'start'    => $media['start'],
                    'end'      => $media['end'],

                    )
                );
            }

 $elasticaType->addDocuments($documents);
 $elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();
```

Please i need your help . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP [does not recommend](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) using uniqid for this use case. Since you are wanting a random, safe id, let Elasticsearch do it for you. The Elastica [Document construct method](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/lib/Elastica/Document.php#L44) notes that the id field is optional. So don't pass it and let Elasticsearch issue the id.

Answer (score 0):

Several things
$elasticaIndex->create (....) you only have to enter it once. Index is unique after creating the index that you can comment or generate a different index and other things. I leave an example that works.

```
class PersistencyElastic
{

private $conection;

public function __construct()
{
$this->conection = new \Elastica\Client(['host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 9200]);
}

public function save($ msg)
{
// $ msg is an array with whatever you want inside
$index = $this->conection->getIndex('googlephotos');

// This is the index I created, it's called googlephotos
// $index->create(array (), true);

$type = $index->getType('googlephotos');

$type->addDocument(new Document (uniqid ('id _', false), $msg, $type, $index));

$index->refresh();
}

}
```